# What does scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) == 2 mean?

Tags: c++, scanf

In the below program, what does the code **scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)==2** do?

The program gets two numbers and print the sum :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    while (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) == 2)
        printf("%d\n", a+b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See the doc http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/?kw=scanf

Comment: This is tagged 'c++' but it looks like C code. In C++ `stdio.h` is deprecated, use `cstdio` instead. Or, better yet, use the I/O facilities in `iostream`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function `scanf` scans input according to format specifier provided as first argument.
`%d` is format specifier for decimal integer so use `%d %d` if you want to match two numbers separated by space.

Other arguments are pointers where matched numbers should be written.

Function 'scanf' returns number of succesfully matched items. The 'while' loop is repeated as long as there were two matched numbers in user-provided input.

Answer (score 4):

`scanf` returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled on success.
In this program, it means if the input is success, the result will be printed and it enters the next loop.
refer to [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

Comment: If `scanf` is not successful, it will still return the number of arguments successfully filled. In fact, it's the non-successful case where the exact return value is most relevant.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf):

> (scanf) Return value: Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned, or EOF if read failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.

Which means, the statement in question means: while scanf successfully read two integer arguments.

Answer (score 0):

From the CC Standard

```
Returns
3 The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs before
the first conversion (if any) has completed. **Otherwise, the scanf function returns the
number of input items** assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in
the event of an early matching failure
```

So the condition in the while loop checks whether exactly two items (numbers) were entered by the user.

```
while (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)==2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Scanf()` returns an integer value and that value is nothing but the number of inputs accepted by `scanf()` function.

`scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)` will return 2 and now our statement becomes

```
while(2 == 2)
{
    // block of code
}
```

i.e `2==2` is true and it means:

```
while(1)
{
    // block of code executed
}
```